# Keep text at the bottom with LinearLayout and ScrollView

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

I am trying to build a menu with multiple options and, at the bottom of the page,  there should be a text. The page should scroll in case the icons don't fit. The text should be at around 6 dp distance from the bottom and some kind of minimum distance from the icons so that they don't overlay if the screen has a different configuration (see figure)

[image]

So far, I have this configuration:

```js
< ScrollView xmlns: android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns: app = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns: tools = "http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android: layout_width = "match_parent"
android: layout_height = "match_parent"
tools: context = ".MainMenu" >

  
  <RelativeLayout
android: layout_width = "match_parent"
android: layout_height = "match_parent"
android: layout_margin = "5dp"
android: gravity = "center_horizontal" >

  
  <LinearLayout
android: layout_width = "match_parent"
android: layout_height = "match_parent"
android: orientation = "vertical" >

   
  <LinearLayout
android: layout_width = "match_parent"
android: layout_height = "match_parent"
android: layout_marginTop = "20dp"
android: orientation = "horizontal" >
  /// More linear layouts

  <
  /LinearLayout> <
  /LinearLayout>

  <
  /RelativeLayout>
  <!--</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>-->
  <
  /ScrollView>
```

So far everything works fine except that fact that I can't make the text stick to the bottom. It feels dependent on the above LinearLayout. I could set a margin to the last layout (the one containing the text), but the number would be a guess, which is not what I want.

Can anyone help me with this?Thanks!!

Comment: can you explain the constraint clearly? do you want the text to be always at the bottom irrespective of height of scrollview? or should the text be part of scrollview as well? How should it look if scrollview size is less than height of screen?

Comment: Thank you. The text should always be at the bottom (6 dp), irrespective of the height. I used scroll view so that it doesn't go over the icons. Not sure if this is the perfect set-up

Comment: just add your `TextView` below your `ScrollView` and put both inside a `LinearLayout`. Then give the `TextView` the required margin

Comment: Thank you, guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think its better if you just put `TextView' outside of`ScrollView`. Solution can be multiple. On simple one can be Using a`RelativeLayout` .

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/txt"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <!-- Your content goes here-->

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked just fine. So if there are many icons, they will not overlay with that bottom text. Is that correct?

Comment: Yeah thats because of `android:layout_above="@+id/txt"` line . Read about `RelativeLayout`  to get more of it . Thx .